# Uninstalling/Installing JDK

Tags: java, windows, uninstallation

For some reason the installation of the oracle JDK didn't work on the machine I am using.  It was installed before I started using it so I figured I would uninstall it and install it properly.  When I try to  uninstall it in Windows I get the following error message:

> Error 1316: A network error occurred while attempting to read from the file C:\Installer\jdk1.7.0_51.msi

This file doesn't exist on this machine, I think it was somehow deleted.  Does anyone know how to get around this problem.

Comment: See if you can reinstall over the top of the existing installation, then uninstall.

Comment: This seems to be already answered here:http://superuser.com/questions/503983/how-can-i-uninstall-java-7-update-5-when-i-dont-have-the-jre1-7-0-05-c-msi-fi

Comment: I tried both of these, first I tried to over install and the installer just told me it is already installed.  I deleted the entries in the registry and I still get the same message.  I am trying to search regedit for other entries to remove.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Installer\Products\4F4A3A46297B6D117AA8000B0D715001  is the key for this version.

Answer (score 3):

I recently experienced the same problem. I solved it using [Microsoft Fix it tool](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/program_install_and_uninstall).

I just launch it and it removes completly the JDK on my computer.